# In Angular2 I have a component that doesnt require a template but I still get a template error

Tags: angular

This is the error I get:

> No template specified for component PageNotFoundComponent    Error: No
>   template specified for component PageNotFoundComponent
>         at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeDirective

This module `/` component redirect user to homepage and logs them out if route doesnt exist e.g. `**`

**This is my component:**

```
import { Directive} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from '../../services/authService/authService';

@Directive({
  selector: 'PageNotFoundComponent'
})

export class PageNotFoundDirective {
  constructor(_authService: AuthService, _router: Router){     
     _authService.isAuthenticated().then(() => {
        _router.navigate(['/home']);
     });
  }
}
```

**This is my module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { PageNotFoundDirective } from './pageNotFound.directive';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/authService/authService';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
  declarations: [PageNotFoundDirective],
  exports: [PageNotFoundDirective],
  providers: [AuthService]
})
export class PageNotFoundModule { }
```

**This is my routes:**

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';
import { PageNotFoundDirective } from './index';

export const PageNotFoundRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundDirective
  }
];
```

This is the current error I get:

> (index):95 Error: (SystemJS) Could not compile 'PageNotFoundDirective'
>   because it is not a component.    Error: Could not compile
>   'PageNotFoundDirective' because it is not a component.

Comment: PageNotFoundModule code could be place inside `AppComponent`, there you can't create a component without template

Comment: I've updated my code now to be a directive

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**update**

For a route you need a component (a directive can't be used here)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'PageNotFoundComponent',
  template: ''
})
```

**original**

There are no components without templates in Angular2

Change

```
 @Component({
```

to

```
 @Directive({
```

and you should get what you want.

Components are directives with a view.

Comment: I've made that change, now I get this error: ReferenceError: Directive is not defined

Comment: `import { Directive } from "@angular/core"`

Comment: You can't use a directive in routes. For this case you need to create a component with an empty template. You can use `@Component({ template: ''})`

Comment: i need it to have a route. I showed you my route above.

Comment: I just saw it - missed that part at first. Just use a component and add `template: ''` to the `@Component(...)` decorator.

Comment: That works now. the  ** route doesnt though. Its meant to redirect to homepage when routes not recognised

Comment: I would to see more routes to be able to tell what's going on.

Comment: I found the problem, I had the ** at the top of the routes, I've moved it to the bottom and now it redirects to homepage if none of routes are matched

Comment: Yes, the order of routes matter and if one matches the router doesn't look for other. `**` matches every route and therefore always matches.